# Volume Up button does not respond while unlocking bootloader

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, fastboot, buttons, bootloader-lock

I have an **InFocus M260** (MediaTek **MT6582** based). It has a locked bootloader and whenever i try to unlock the bootloader, this shows up :

> fastboot -i 0x0489 oem unlock

in the device it shows

```
press volume up for Yes
press volume down for no
```

I press my volume up button but I get no response...
When I press my volume down button it says

```
returning to fastboot in 3s
```

Can anyone help me please!! I am not able to flash custom recoveries to my phone.. :(